# Spring Security authentication from custom tables

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

I was looking into spring security, it has good features, but my requirement is bit different.
I have one table: 1. Employee (fields ename, epassword)

I want to authenticate user from this table but using spring security.
I know spring security has kinda feature of enable and ROLE but didn't able to get how I can get authentication from my table.
I have seen some examples and google certain link but some good links will be more helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have a custom `UserDetailsService` and give an implementation for  `loadUserByUsername(String username)` to load user info from the database. After that, you can have a custom implementation of `AuthenticationProvider` which uses your custom `UserDetailsService` to authenticate the user. Spring security is also having the same kind of implementation to authenticate the user from table, but have some limitation on table structure, etc. You can have a look on `DaoAuthenticationProvider` to implement your own `AuthenticationProvider` and `JdbcDaoImpl` to have your custom `UserDetailsService`.

Comment: Do you want to say "You can have custom ..." rather than "cutom"?